# How can I convert a list of nested lists of dataframes into a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, nested-lists

My question is related to the conversion of a list of nested lists of dataframes into a **single** dataframe.

For a simple example let's use the `iris` dataset.

```
#import of library
library(purrr)
#import of the dataset
data(iris)
#creation of lists
lst=list(`0`=list(`1`=iris[1:5,]),`18`=c(`1`=list(iris[1:5,]),`2`=list(iris[1:5,])))
```

How can I merge all the dataframes of the nested lists into an one dataframe?

Comment: @Anas.S Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Pablo Rod I tried it and I got this message "Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Argument 1 can't be a list containing data frames"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, loop inside 0, 18 and `bind_rows` then use `map_dfr` to bind rows of the higher element i.e to bind 0 and 18 together.

```
library(purrr)
lst=list(`0`=list(`1`=iris[1:5,]),`18`=c(`1`=list(iris[1:5,]),`2`=list(iris[1:5,])))
map_dfr(ls,~bind_rows(.,.id='id'))
#OR
bind_rows(unlist(lst,recursive = FALSE),.id = 'id')
```

Another more save option is to use `unlist` and `purrr::imap` to produce column *id* represents the full path of each dataframe

```
imap_dfr(unlist(lst,recursive = FALSE), ~data.frame(id=.y, .x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

     id Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1   0.1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2   0.1          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3   0.1          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4   0.1          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5   0.1          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6  18.1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
7  18.1          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
8  18.1          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
9  18.1          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
10 18.1          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
11 18.2          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
12 18.2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
13 18.2          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
14 18.2          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
15 18.2          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```